# redirect not working in PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using jQuery autocomplete and trying to get it to go directly to the link when I click on suggestion or press enter. Here's the code I used:

```
        <script>
        $(function() {
        $( "#search" ).autocomplete({
        source: 'search.php',
        select: function(event, ui) {
         $(this).val(ui.item.value);
         $(this).parents("form").submit();  // this will submit the form.
   }
        });
        });
</script>
```

Then I have my php code for search: '

```
if ($_POST['search'] != null) {
                                //die("asdf: " . $_POST['search']);
                                $search = $_POST['search'];
                                $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM question WHERE text LIKE '%$search%'");
                                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                                $text = $row['text'];
                                $question_id = $row['question_id'];
                                //die($search . " " . $text);
                                if ($search == $text){
                                    header("Location: http://localhost/showstats.php?question_id=$question_id");
                                    die();
                                }
                                echo "<br>";
                                echo " <a href=\"showstats.php?question_id=" . $question_id;
                                echo "\">$text</a> ";
                                //echo "<br>";
                            }}
```

The problem is when I click on suggestion it doesn't redirect to `"showstats.php?question_id=$question_id"`, insted give me a blank result page.
And when I insert `die($search . " " . $text);` inside if statement it's showing me text 2 times, so I know it enters the body of it statement.

Comment: Add error reporting in `showstats.php`. Does it give you any message?

Comment: You never actually close your `while(){` loop, so therefore you are encountering a parse error. or you never close your `if(){` statement, one of the 2.

Comment: No, in fact it doesn't redirect it stays on stats.php(page where search is), and it shows no results. That's the problem it doesn't redirect at all...

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I see it closed... Not well indented yet closed

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I close it made an error when posting the code.

Comment: Could you provide a link please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you select a suggestion, the event occurs in the client so this code in your PHP is not really necessary:

```
if ($search == $text) {
    header("Location: http://localhost/showstats.php?question_id=$question_id");
    die();
}
```

Instead, when you select a suggestion, try triggering the redirection from jQuery:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#search" ).autocomplete({
        source: 'search.php',
        select: function(event, ui) {
            // This will redirect you to whatever URL is in ui.item.value:
            window.location = ui.item.value;
       }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: But the value of ui.item.value is the suggestion text, not the showstats.php?question_id=$question_id. I tried to enter my link using: window.location.href = "showstats.php?question_id=ui.item.value"; But, logically it returns suggestion text, not question_id that I need because I made search.php to return text not question_id. So, how can I do this?

Comment: I figured it out. I need to set value to quesiton_id in my search.php. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

also worth escaping your sql...

$search = $_POST['search'];
$search = mysqli_real_escape_string($search);
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM question WHERE text LIKE '%$search%'") or die(mysqli_error($con));

Answer (score 0):

It is because your headers are already sent, you have started your output, hence the redirect will not work.

Try buffering your output.